# How to prevent db connection code chunks from evaluating in Rmd?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have a .RMD file that I knit to generate reports. In the beginning of the doc, there is a code chunk that executes a query on a remote DB and returns some data as an output (typical select query from joins of different tables). The data that is being generated is quite fixed in the sense that I'm retrieving data from a certain date interval and this date interval that I'm performing the analysis on doesn't change.
Each time I make an appearance related change in the .RMD file and I knit it, it runs this query which takes >2 minutes to run as quite some data is being returned. I don't want this to happen since the base data that I'm performing analysis on doesn't change at all.
How do I ensure this one block alone doesn't evaluate all the time? I have tried putting `eval = FALSE`
However I get the following error:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate") : no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "function" Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> %>% -> mutate Execution halted`<br><br>
```

For context, df is the data frame that is returned after execution of the query through dbExecuteQuery(). As soon as the chunk that has eval = FALSE is executed, I have another chunk that performs mutate() on it. That is where the error is generated.

The code chunk with `eval=FALSE` is a just a generic sql execution code chunk. The chunk's content goes something like this:

```
query <- 'select * from table1 join table2'
query2 <- 'select * from table3'
df1 <- dbGetQuery(conn,query)
df2 <- dbGetQuery(conn,query2)
df < - left_join(df1,df2)
```

The next code chunk where the error originates from does something like this:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(newcol = is.na(somecol))
```

I found an answer on Stackoverflow that kinda sorta explains my problem but with no satisfactory solution.
Link to SF post: [error knitting flex dashboard rmarkdown dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53407695/error-knitting-flex-dashboard-rmarkdown-dplyr)

Answer (score 1):

I assume, even if you get the error message, you receive it before the 2 minute mark, which would it take if this chunk would be evaluated, right? So the eval = FALSE shouldn't be the problem at all. If you don't need to run the query again and again, I assume that you stored the data locally?

The error message itself could pop up because of a package conflict, maybe try dplyr::mutate?

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps try with [memoise](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/memoise/versions/2.0.0/topics/memoise)

it'd be something like:

```r
query <- 'select * from table1 join table2'
query2 <- 'select * from table3'
my.get.query <- memoise( dbGetQuery )
df1 <- my.get.query(conn,query)
df2 <- my.get.query(conn,query2)
df < - left_join(df1,df2)
```

This may not work, it depends entirely on how knitting is operated, if it starts fresh with a new session or not.

Otherwise write your own function that caches the results to a file.